# React : state object property is not updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am trying to update my my state but in meantime when I console updated state value in console it give me a message that your state value is `undefined` . could someon eplease help me how to solve this problem . I am using `rc-time-picker` for picking a time and storing a selected time in localstorage but it did not updating state value 
Thanks

**Code**

```
import 'rc-time-picker/assets/index.css';
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import TimePicker from 'rc-time-picker';
import moment from 'moment';

const format = 'h:mm a';



const now = moment().hour(0).minute(0);

class Time extends Component {

  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state={
      value : ''
    }
  }

  newHandleChange=(value)=>{
    this.setState({
        value:   localStorage.setItem("currentTime",value.format('h:mm a'))
    })

}
  render(){
    console.log("state data",this.state.value)

    return(
      <div>
           <TimePicker
                  showSecond={false}
                  defaultValue={now}
                  className="xxx"
                  onChange={this.newHandleChange}
                  format={format}
                  use12Hours
                  inputReadOnly
                  fieldName="time"
                />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Time;
```

Comment: localStorage.setItem returns undefined, and you are setting state with that undefined.

Comment: Separate from the `getItem` error, you do need to pass on the argument your constructor gets called with (`props`). Or don't define a constructor at all and declare `state` with a field declaration (Stage 3, almost always transpiled in React setups).

Answer (score 2):

The reason why you're getting `undefined` is because you're setting new state with the value that gets returned from calling `localStorage.setItem`, which is `undefined`.

Here's what you need to do instead:

```js
class Time extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { value: '' }
  }

  // ...

  newHandleChange = (value) => {
    const time = value.format('h:mm a')

    localStorage.setItem('currentTime', time)
    this.setState({
      value: time
    })
  }
}
```

This way, you're saving your new time into a variable and using it to update `currentValue` in `localStorage` and `state` in your component.

Comment: with this it not sending correct select value to database when I think it using previous value because I am selecting from drop down everytime when user click on something it updating localstorage

Comment: @goto1 - No, I'm asking whoever downvoted your answer why they did so.

Comment: @Jonas that's not what your original question was asking for - this is a valid solution to the problem you described above. Your database call using an incorrect value is another issue that is happening somewhere else..

Comment: @Jonas - This code corrects the error in your code in the question. If you're having issues with saving to a database, that's in *different* code, and not an issue with this correct answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

When initializing `state` in `constructor` you should pass `props` to `super`:

```
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      value : ''
    }
  }
```

The `undefined` you're getting is just the result from `getItem()`

Comment: It is now. The undefined it's just the result from `localStorage.getItem()` call

Comment: could you please answer

Comment: You should pass initialize `state` like above. But the `undefined` you're getting is just `localStorage` returning `undefined`

Answer (score -1):

You need to set the proper value to the state, please check below code

```
  newHandleChange=(value)=>{
    localStorage.setItem("currentTime",value.format('h:mm a')) // if you really needs the local storage.

    this.setState({
        value: value.format('h:mm a')
    })
  }
```

Comment: FWIW, I can see two possible reasons: 1. No explanation. 2. Formatting twice. Most #1 I'd guess.

Answer (score -1):

try to used this `

```
newHandleChange =val=> {
const value=localStorage.setItem('currentTime', val.format('h:mm a'))

    this.setState({
      value
    })
  }`
```

look to this  this app https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-bohr-6jon1